# Any way to make RxDB work for React Native on Expo with a SQLite database (I own a RxDB Premium, the SQLite Plugin does not work)

Tags: sqlite, rxdb

The author mentions that his premium plugin `rxdb-premium/plugins/storage-sqlite` is not working on older version of SQLite on Android, if we get the error mentionned below (in the next code block). So, `expo` uses SQLite version `3.32.2` instead of `3.38.0` to use `JSON_EXTRACT`.

Anyone found a way to make expo work with his plugin without using `pouchdb-adapter` on Android with any react-native SQLite database? I know that `expo-sqlite` works only on `iOS`, like he said it would.

The error below, and [his page](https://rxdb.info/rx-storage-sqlite.html) mentionning the error in the "requirements" section

```js
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Array [
  Object {
    "error": [Error: no such function: JSON_EXTRACT (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "rxdb_deleted_lastWriteTime_idx" ON "_rxdb_internal-0"(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.deleted'), JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.lastWriteTime'), deleted);],
  },
]
```

I will like to use his storage wrapper for expo `getSQLiteBasicsExpoSQLite` with a sqlite database that works. I tried :

- **expo-sqlite**: missing JSON_EXTRACT https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/expo-sqlite-ship-newer-sqlite3-version-on-android
- **react-native-sqlite-storage**:
  `TypeError: e is not a function. (In 'e(r)', 'e' is undefined)`
- **react-native-sqlite-2**: (does not load with expo) `{"name":"TypeError","message":"null is not an object (evaluating 'RNSqlite2.exec')"`
- **react-native-quick-sqlite**: (does not load with expo)
  `Error: Base quick-sqlite module not found.`

I get my storage like so:

```js
import * as exposqlite from 'expo-sqlite';
import sqlite2 from 'react-native-sqlite-2';
import { getRxStorageSQLite, getSQLiteBasicsExpoSQLite } from 'rxdb-premium/plugins/storage-sqlite';

function getStorage(key: 'expo' | 'sqlite2' | 'memory') {
  switch(key) {
    case 'expo':
      return getRxStorageSQLite({
        sqliteBasics: getSQLiteBasicsExpoSQLite(exposqlite.openDatabase),
      });
    case 'sqlite2':
      return getRxStorageSQLite({
        sqliteBasics: getSQLiteBasicsWebSQL(sqlite2.openDatabase),
      });
    // and more attempts... on differents storage to make expo work with any sqlite db.
    case 'memory':
    default:
      return getRxStorageMemory();
  }
}

function createDatabase() {
  const storage = getStorage('expo');
  const db = await createRxDatabase<RxCollections>({
    eventReduce: true,
    multiInstance: false,
    name: storage.name,
    password: env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    storage,
    ignoreDuplicate: false,
  });

  await db.addCollections(collections);

  console.info('RxDB: Database created.');

  return db;
}
```

these are some libs from my `package.json` :

```json
"expo": "47.0.8",
"expo-sqlite": "11.1.1",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-dom": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.5",
"react-native-sqlite-storage": "6.0.1",
"react-native-sqlite-2": "3.6.2",
"rxdb": "14.1.9",
"rxdb-premium": "14.1.9",
"rxjs": "7.8.0",
```

I also disabled pretty much all other features and only render a splash screen to wait for the db to mount and resolve, so no replications, so I have no data to insert in the database, only waiting it to mount.

I would like to find a way to make sqlite work with rxdb and expo.

EDIT: I made my own module [expo-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/jwallet/expo-sqlite-storage) but it cannot be used inside ExpoGO until the expo team upgrade their module **expo-sqlite**. This module is the same as the original, except it uses `requery/sqlite-android` database instead of `android.database.sqlite` to a more updated version of sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked here?
https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb/tree/master/examples/react-native

I managed to get the example working with Expo after updating the RN version.

Comment: This is half a clarification question (which should be in a comment instead of an answer post) and half a link-only answer (which is usually deleted on StackOverflow, because the answer itself is supposed to be right here). Linking and summarizing *how* the solution works (in contrast advertising * what* it achieves) would be OK. But you seem to just confirm *that* it works - not how. Please [edit] to make more obvious how this is an answer according to [answer].